# How to get reference to newly created record?

Tags: ember.js

I have following use case: 'I create resource 'project' in action handler in a controller, after that I'd like to make a transition to a newly created `route`'. My intentions looks something like this:

```
 createNewProject: function() {
    this.store.createRecord('project', {
      title:                    this.get('title'),
      description:              this.get('description'),
      full_description:         this.get('full_description')
    }).then((project) => {
       this.transitionToRoute('projects.show', project);
    });
  }
```

but it doesn't work like that because `createRecord` doesn't return a `promise` as far as I know, maybe there is some work around ?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

createRecord returns the record itself, because it don't need to do a network request.
To do the network request you need to call .save() on the new record and this returns a promise. This will work but won't save your record to the Server:

```
createNewProject: function() {
  let project  = this.store.createRecord('project', {
    title:                    this.get('title'),
    description:              this.get('description'),
    full_description:         this.get('full_description')
  })

  this.transitionToRoute('projects.show', project);
}
```

To save your Record call `project.save()` before calling `transitionToRoute`. This will save your Record async and transition to the new Route immediately. To wait for the successful save before doing the transition do this:

```
project.save().then(() => this.transitionToRoute(project));
```

Comment: continuing what you said about saving record to the server, you mean something like this ```project.save().then((project) => {
        this.transitionToRoute('projects.show', project);
      });```